# Android Chirp Installation 12345

Tags: chirp

Exist an installer for the application? Not everyone has such advanced knowledge to configure these SDKs.

Additionally I am not roots on my Android

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask.  Please consider improving your question after reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2):

By the definition an SDK is a software development kit which means it is designed for developers. Chirp.io as a software company does not provide end customers applications so the only way to use Chirp is to learn how to build your own application using Chirp SDKs.